# How to call a plot resulted from a reactive function in downloadHandler

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

How can I call a plot that's created with a reactive function in `downloadHandler` without defining it all over again?

Non-working example:

```
# Part of server.R

output$tgPlot <- renderPlot({
 plot1 <-ggplot(iris[iris$Species==input$species,])+geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length ,Sepal.Width))
 print(plot1)

 } ) 



  output$plotsave <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'plot.pdf',
    content = function(file){
      pdf(file = file, width=12, height=4)
      tgPlot()
      dev.off()
    }
  )
```

Why can't you call tgPlot() in `downloadHandler`? Is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `tgPlot()` a function that's defined somewhere else? I don't see you ever define that.

You likely want to define your plotting code in a regular (non-reactive) function which you reference from both functions, a la:

```
tgPlot <- function(inputSpecies){
 plot1 <-ggplot(iris[iris$Species==inputSpecies,])+geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length ,Sepal.Width))
 print(plot1)
}

output$tgPlot <- renderPlot({
    tgPlot(input$species)
}) 

output$plotsave <- downloadHandler(
  filename = 'plot.pdf',
  content = function(file){
    pdf(file = file, width=12, height=4)
    tgPlot(input$species)
    dev.off()
  }
)
```

That gives you a function that can generate your plot. This function can then be referenced within a reactive `renderPlot` context to generate a reactive Plot, or to generate a PDF.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I mean. I would like to call `output$tgPlot` similar to the method used here for datasets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592225/how-can-i-pass-data-between-functions-in-a-shiny-app. This would be handy when you have a lot of different conditional plots as possible output of `output$tgPlot`.

Comment: JT85, Jeff is right--you'll need to do the plot twice, using a non-reactive function. This is because in one case (`renderPlot`) it's a PNG that's being rendered, in the other case it's a PDF, these are two totally different operations that just happen to share some common logic (i.e. `tgPlot`).