# Multiplot on the same graph with checkboxGroupInput in a Shiny App

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I want to plot on the same graph one or more plots, depending on the boxes checked in my "checkboxGroupInput". 
After checking a few topics on SO, I have found that a easy-to-use solution would be to add "add=TRUE" in the second, third...plots.

Here is a simplified copy of my code :
Server.R

```
function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    #I use getMyPlotValues with two parameters. 
    #idFcast is the one which doesn't work.

    m_PARAM$idSite <- input$country
    m_PARAM$idFcast <- input$model[i]

    getMyPlotValues(m_PARAM)
  })  

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

                      ## We plot all the models on the same graph.
                      if(length(input$model) > 0)
                      {
                        firstplot<- TRUE 
                        #To put add = TRUE for the second, third... plots

                        for(i in 1:length(input$model))
                        {
                          valueshere <- dataInput()
                          #We pick up the vectors (ts,obs) with the function
                          #And plot them. 
                          if(firstplot)
                          {
                            plot(valueshere$ts,valueshere$obs)
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            plot(valueshere$ts,valueshere$obs,add=TRUE)
                          }
                          firstplot <- FALSE
                        } 

                      }

                  })
  }
```

And now the UI.R simplified :

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

  fluidRow(
    column((4),
           selectInput("country", label = h3("Pays"), 
                       choices = list("First" = 2,"Second" = 1), selected = 1)
    )

  fluidRow( 

      #checkboxGroupInput
    column(6, 
           checkboxGroupInput("model", 

                              choices = list("First" = 1,"Second"=2,"Third"=3),
                              selected = 1)
    )


  )

),

mainPanel
(

plotOutput("plot1")
)
  )
)

)
```

I found on this topic ([How can I pass data between functions in a Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592225/how-can-i-pass-data-between-functions-in-a-shiny-app))  that I could try to pass the variable "i" by writing valueshere <- dataInput()$i... Because I have the feeling this is where the error comes from. I try do display input$model and it works, input$model[i] doesn't.

There must be a problem in my code, as I am a beginner in Shiny, but I couldn't fix, even with all the topics about Shiny on SO.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that `add` argument isn't work. I finished with the solution that consists in creating plots for all your models and only displays them when it's value is selected. So here is:

I have tried to make your example reproduceble so you will observe some changes

**UPDATE**: Supposing your SQL statement will give you a vector with your model names (`models_list`) you could generate Shiny objects using `lapply` (like [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html))

```
library(shiny)
# Simulate data
set.seed(189)
df <- data.frame("obs" = 1:30, "ts" = (rnorm(30)+100)
                 , "country" = rep(c("First", "Second"), 15)
                 , "models" = rep(c("First", "Second", "Third"), 10),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# Suppose your SQL query returns this kind of output
models_list <- c("First", "Second", "Third")
models_num <- length(models_list)

# Run App
shiny::runApp(list(

  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("country", label = "Countries", 
                    choices = c("First", "Second"), selected =  "First"),
        checkboxGroupInput("model", label = "Models",
                           choices = c("First", "Second", "Third"),
                           selected = "First")
      ),

      mainPanel(

        lapply(1:models_num, function(i) {
          plotOutput(paste0('plot', i))
        })

      )
    )

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    dataInput <- reactive({
      df_out <- df[(df$country == input$country), ]
      return(df_out)
    })  

    lapply(1:models_num, function(i) {
      output[[paste0('plot', i)]] <- renderPlot({
        if(any(input$model %in% models_list[i])){
          valueshere <- dataInput()[df$models == models_list[i],]
          plot(valueshere$ts,valueshere$obs)
        }
      })
    })

  }
))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help !
Actually, I will have a variable number of "models", coming from a SQL request, which means I can't fix the problem by listing directly all the models. Thats's why I tried the for loop with : "for(i in 1:length(input$model))". 
Sorry for the test game, I should have put it in the document to make it ready-to-work. I don't know if you have any solution to make it work ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great ! I am not used to work with the function lapply, but it works better with it ;) Don't know why it couldn't work with a for loop :/ Thanks and see you !

Comment: `lapply` returns a list, when for loop evaluates a statement on each iteration. I guess that is the point. Glad to help you!

Comment: I have found on another topic thats it's possible to plot several graphs in same plot by replacing the following plot by "lines". That solves my problem 'til the end now !

Comment: you can also check out `rCharts` for interactive plots. I use them in my shiny apps and very satisfied