# Accessing a data frame loaded from read.csv from another function - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm having trouble passing the data from a matrix that I read from a csv file to another function.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592225/how-can-i-pass-data-between-functions-in-a-shiny-app), creating an auxiliary data function and calling the matrix using `data()$loadedMat`.

I'm getting

**Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable**

I have:

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

   data <- reactive(function (){

       inFile <- input$file1

       if (is.null(inFile))
         return(NULL)

       loadedFile <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, 
                              header=FALSE, 
                              sep=input$sep, 
                              quote=input$quote)

       loadedDf <- loadedFile[2:nrow(loadedFile), ]

       #figure out how to access loadedMat from another function
       loadedMat <- as.matrix(loadedDf)


     })

     output$result <- renderText({

          input$goButton 
          x <- someFunction(data()$loadedMat)
     })
 })
```

Comment: Redefining `data()` seems like a bad idea; pick another name, or your code is going to get really confusing to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reactive function `data()` doesn't "contain" the matrix `loadedMat`, it *is* `loadedMat`.

So you would access it like `x <- someFunction(data())`

The answer you link to highlights how you would acccess columns from the data.frame.

To access columns of a `data.frame` you would go `data$column`. The same applies for reactive data frames: `data()$column`

---

Reiterating @alistaire's comment: you should probably pick a different name for your data than `data` (as `data()` is already a function in R)